# $Cov(\hat{\epsilon})$ in a linear regression model

Tags: regression

[image]

I proved the result myself too, but my proof was a lot lengthier. Apparently however, it can be done in just these two lines. However, I don't really get the first step here. Could anyone please explain me why the first equality holds?

Comment: Please tell us what $Z,$ $\varepsilon,$ $\hat{\varepsilon},$ and $\sigma$ represent.  In particular, what formulas do you know that express $\hat{\varepsilon}$  in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $Z$?  (In so doing, I suspect you will find the answer to this question yourself.)

Comment: @whuber $\hat{y}=Z \hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon}$. The epsilons are the error terms and $\sigma^2$ is variance. I still however don't know why this holds...

Comment: That's because you expressed $\hat{y}$ rather than $\hat{\varepsilon}$ in terms of $Z$.  You might find that searching our site for ["idempotent"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=idempotent) gives particularly helpful pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$
\hat{\epsilon} = y - Z\hat{\beta}
$$

the usual estimator of $\beta$ is

$$
\hat{\beta} = (Z^{T}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}y
$$

which gives

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}\hat{\epsilon} &=& y - Z(Z^{T}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}y\\&=&\left[I - Z(Z^{T}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}\right]y\end{array}
$$

and so

$$
Cov[\hat{\epsilon}] = Cov\left[\left[I - Z(Z^{T}Z)^{-1}Z^{T}\right]y\right]
$$

then simply use the property

$$
Cov[Ax] = ACov[x]A^{T}
$$